# Альтернатива скалярной функции

Tags: sql, sql-server

В общем, нужно сосчитать некоторое значение, которое высчитывается путем JOIN'ов нескольких больших таблиц, а так же с использование `CASE WHEN` в `SELECT`.

Если эта логика встроена в сам запрос, то выполняется SCAN'ы таблиц и запрос шустро отрабатывает, а если все это помещать в скалярную функцию, то выбирается SEEK(логично), но и запрос медленно выполняется.

Какая может быть оптимальная альтернатива скаляру, что бы все было красиво(уродливый CASE был спрятан с JOIN'ами), но в тоже время, я мог ее вызвать в запрос с большим кол-вом записей и она бы работала, как будто встроена в основной запрос?

Comment: _"Какая может быть оптимальная альтернатива скаляру"_ - либо _view_, либо _inline TVF_ (функция с табличным значением).